# Pascal triangle matrix using vectors in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, stdvector

I need make Pascal Triangle matrix using vectors and then print it.

This algorithm would work with arrays, but somehow it doesn't work with matrix using vectors.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix;

int NumberOfRows(Matrix m) { return m.size(); }
int NumberOfColumns(Matrix m) {
  if (m.size() != 0)
    return m[0].size();
  return 0;
}

Matrix PascalTriangle(int n) {
  Matrix mat;
  int a;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    a = 1;
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      if (j == 1)
        mat.push_back(j);
      else
        mat.push_back(a);
      a = a * (i - j) / j;
    }
  }
  return mat;
}

void PrintMatrix(Matrix m, int width) {
  for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfRows(m); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < NumberOfColumns(m); j++)
      std::cout << std::setw(width) << m[i][j];
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  Matrix m = PascalTriangle(7);
  PrintMatrix(m, 10);

  return 0;
}
```

I get nothing on screen, and here's the same code just without matrix using vectors [program](https://onlinegdb.com/LdhxIlUtL) (which works fine).

Could you help me fix this code?

Comment: `Matrix mat;` -- How do you add elements to an empty vector?  I see no calls to `push_back`, `insert`, `emplace_back`, `resize`, etc.

Comment: I tried `push_back` it doesn't work

Comment: *I get nothing on screen* -- Well, I [certainly see something](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56b3a5d91373c849), (segmentation fault), and it is related to the first comment.

Comment: Since we do not see the code with `push_back`, the issue is that you are using it incorrectly in some way.  There is absolutely nothing wrong with `push_back`.  Regardless, the current code you have is a non-starter -- you don't add elements to a vector by using `[]`.

Comment: I added `push_back` to my code

Comment: Your `Matrix` has **two** vectors, not one.  Where is the call to add elements to the "inner" vector?  Thus this looks like an issue with your logic -- you have to take into account you have an "outer" vector and an "inner" vector to take care of.

Comment: I don't know how to add elements to "inner" vector. Could you help me?

Comment: Please don't change your original code.  Add the new code as an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that in `PascalTriangle`, you are starting out with an empty `Matrix` in both the number of rows and columns.

Since my comments mentioned `push_back`, here is the way to use it if you did not initialize the `Matrix` with the number of elements that are passed in.

The other issue is that `NumberOfColumns` should specify the row, not just the matrix vector.

The final issue is that you should be passing the `Matrix` by const reference, not by value.

Addressing all of these issues, results in this:

```
Matrix PascalTriangle(int n) 
{
    Matrix mat;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mat.push_back({}); // creates a new empty row
        std::vector<int>& newRow = mat.back(); // get reference to this row
        int a = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) 
        { 
            if (j == 0) 
                newRow.push_back(1);
            else
                newRow.push_back(a);
            a = a * (i - j) / (j + 1); 
        }
    }
    return mat;
}
```

And then in `NumberOfColumns`:

```
int NumberOfColumns(const Matrix& m, int row) 
{
    if (!m.empty())
        return m[row].size();
    return 0;
}
```

And then, `NumberOfRows`:

```
int NumberOfRows(const Matrix& m) { return m.size(); }
```

And last, `PrintMatrix`:

```
void PrintMatrix(const Matrix& m, int width) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfRows(m); i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NumberOfColumns(m, i); j++)
            std::cout << std::setw(width) << m[i][j];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here is a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac78f31e0e8ef1e0)

Comment: is there any way to do this without getting reference of row? Because we didn't learn references yet

Comment: I got the reference to the last row because it is easier to handle in terms of typing, and ease of use.  You could have still used `mat.back().push_back(1);` for example.  And yes, to properly get the last element of a vector is to use `back()`.  If you really and truly didn't want to use `back()`, then `mat[mat.size()-1].push_back(1)` would be done.  But what looks easier and less error prone to you?

Comment: could you please edit your code to work without reference?

Comment: Which reference are you referring to?  I won't edit the answer if you are talking about the passing of `Matrix` by reference.  That is a big part of the answer I posted.

Comment: I'm talking about all references used

Comment: I leave it to you to remove the references.  I make it a habit to not post bad C++ coding.  Answers on StackOverflow should reflect proper coding style.

Comment: would this work just by `const Matrix &m` changed to `Matrix m`?

Comment: Yes, it would work, but every time you pass `Matrix m`, you are creating a temporary copy of that entire matrix.  That's why it should be passed by const reference, so that you do not incur the temporary copy.  I don't know if you are coming from Java or C# or similar language, but C++ does **not** pass by reference by default (like those other languages).  It is important to know the difference between passing `Matrix m` and passing `Matrix& m`.

Comment: so it's definitely better to use references, thank you very much, I'm coming from C, just as I learned C, I came to a bottomless C ++ ocean :)

Comment: I'm having problem with trying to not use reference for row... Could you help me to fix this https://onlinegdb.com/ob6_QZh80 error: `conversion from ‘void’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector’ requested`

Comment: Get rid of `newRow` altogether if you don't want to use references, and please refer to my earlier comment about `mat.back()`.  And your attempt makes my earlier point -- which way is easier and less error-prone?  The odd thing is that getting a reference is *exactly* what you are trying to do long-hand, so I really don't know why you insist on doing 2+2+2+2 instead of 2 x 4.

Comment: [Using mat.back()](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d3ac78063e90e0b)

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile because you have numerous errors in `PascalTriangle`.

For one, you initialize a matrix with no elements. Additionally, you use matrix indices starting at 1 rather than 0.

The following prints things for me:

```
Matrix PascalTriangle(int n) {
  Matrix mat(n, std::vector<int>(n, 0)); // Construct Matrix Properly
  int a;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // Start index at 0
    a = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) { // Start index at 0
      if (j == 0) // Changed 1 to 0
        mat[i][j] = 1;
      else
        mat[i][j] = a;
      a = a * (i - j) / (j+1); // Changed j to j+1 since j starts at 0
    }
  }
  return mat;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but this doesn't print correct output like here https://www.onlinegdb.com/LdhxIlUtL

Comment: Sorry I had a slight typo (I just fixed it). You need to loop for `j < i+1` instead of `j<i`

Comment: The one issue with this is that you are creating an `n x n` matrix, when in actuality, the size can be smaller than `n x n` for Pascal's triangle.  The solution would be to only add data to a row when necessary.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes, but the OP isn't in a situation where he needs to save every byte of memory he can get. Either way, the memory complexity is the same.